# htaccess RewriteRule not processing if not all parameters are passed

Tags: .htaccess

Hoping someone can help me with this issue...

I have a RewriteRule set up in my htaccess file that looks like this

```
RewriteRule ^/?find/(.+)/?in/(.+)/(.+)/ /page.html?&type=$1&city=$2&state_abbrev=$3 [L,QSA]
```

The rewrite works fine if I have a URL that contains all the parameters specified for example: http://www.site.com/find/doctors/in/dallas/tx/

The issue is, I would like to have this rewrite work even if one of the parameters is missing.  For example, if I only entered http://www.site.com/find/doctors/ I would still want it to redirect to 'page.html' and just not have the parameters completed.  So in that case it would be writing to http://www.site.com/page.html?type=doctors&city=&state_abbrev=.  Currently, if I type in a URL that doesn't have all parameters in it the RewriteRule will not work.  Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: and other parameters?, should /find//in//tx/ to redirect to  page.html?type=&city=&state_abbrev=tx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?find/([^/]+)(?:/in/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?)? /page.html?type=$1&city=$2&state_abbrev=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: You're welcome @Pjack. Good to know that it worked out for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you from having multiple rewrites. I have many in my .htaccess for different things and many times you have to. Not one rewrite will work for all occasions.

You could try this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^find/(.*)/in/(.*)/(.*) page.html?type=$1&city=$2&state_abbrev=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^find/(.*) page.html?type=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

It will first look for the full URL

```
http://www.site.com/find/doctors/in/dallas/tx
```

Then forward it to the first Rewrite rule.

But then if you used this

```
http://www.site.com/find/doctors
```

It will skip the first rule and it will match the 2nd rule redirecting to just the partial query string.

Hope that helps but you can make as many `rules` or `conditions` you want. And the order in which they come **does** matter.

Comment: No problem, glad you got a working solution. If it's useful at all you can always upvote.